# How can I set a width for a textbox within a stackpanel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a TextBox placed inside a StackPanel in WPF.  If I set the Width or MaxWidth properties on the TextBox, its width does not change.

I can set the width of the StackPanel, but it cuts off the TextBox instead of changing the width.

Do I have to set a different property or put the TextBox in a different container in order to change its width?

Test Xaml Below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Service: "/>
    <TextBox Width="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting both the Width and MinWidth properties on the TextBox solved this problem.